# JSONP over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, cross-domain, jsonp, cors

Is it possible to send a jsonp-Request from domain http://www.a.com (not under my control) to domain www.b.com (under my control) through https? If so, are the parameter values in the GET-Request encrypted or do they be logged in access-logs in plain text?

I'm searching a secure way to do cross domain request. Unfortunately POST-Statements through CORS requests / SSL doesn't work with Internet Explorer. It doesn't support setting cookies by Access-Control-Allow-Credentials. Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Which version of IE are you taking about or are they all affected up to v10?

Comment: IE < 8 doesn't support CORS. IE 8 and 9 support only XDomainReques which doen't support Access-Control-Allow-Credentials/Setting cookies with request; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) and IE 10 has probably a bug when using withCredential=true (http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors -> Known Issues)

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question , HTTPS will only encrypt the channel the request uses to transfer the data. Once it arrives at the web server all the request params will be logged in your access log in plain text.

You would need to use a POST request to prevent the data being written to the access log. However you cant use JSONP over a POST request (not possible to send a POST request using a  tag).